# How do I move these arrows down to be centered in the column?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the size and move the up and down arrows to be centered in their respective column.
Here is a screenshot of the problem.
[Screenshot of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH504.jpg)

Here's the HTML code of one of the table columns(All 5 columns have essentially the same code):

```
<td>
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "column1">
         <img id="slideShirt" class = "IMGsize" src="https://..." alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1">
            <h3 class = "shirt" id ="shirtName">
               <center>Shirt 1</center> 
            </h3> 
     </div>

     <div class = "column2">
        <img onclick="nextShirt()" class = "arrow" src="https://..." alt="Up arrow">
        <br>
        <img onclick="previousShirt()" class = "arrow" src="https://..." alt="down arrow">
     </div>  
  </div> 
</td>
```

The image of the shirt is in "column 1" and the up and down arrows are in "column 2"

Here is the CSS code that goes with the columns and images of the arrows:

```
.column1 {
    
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height:85%;
}

.column2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;  
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

img.arrow {
  height: 115%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

For some reason, I can't change the size or position of the arrows using the "arrow" class. The arrows are in column 2 but everything in column 2 looks like it would make the image centered but it's not.
Any and all help/ideas are welcomed. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.column1 .IMGsize {
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34473778)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Please also take a look at [Grid Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp), which is more suited for this. However, if you want to continue using a table, the example I have added to this answer will help you.

It seems like you're not fully leveraging the table layout. Here's a way this can be done with a minimal amount of CSS:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <img id="slideShirt" class="IMGsize" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img onclick="nextShirt()" class="arrow" src="https://..." alt="Up arrow">
          <br>
          <img onclick="previousShirt()" class="arrow" src="https://..." alt="down arrow">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 class="shirt" id="shirtName">
        <center>Shirt 1</center>
      </h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <img id="slideShirt" class="IMGsize" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img onclick="nextShirt()" class="arrow" src="https://..." alt="Up arrow">
          <br>
          <img onclick="previousShirt()" class="arrow" src="https://..." alt="down arrow">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 class="shirt" id="shirtName">
        <center>Shirt 1</center>
      </h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see the arrows are aligned vertically to the center of the image.